# Map two mixed columns with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a dataframe where two columns, `User` and `Code`, have their values mixed or not correctly filled.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"User":['Dan', 'Mary','003','010','Luke','Peter'],"Code":['001','035','003','Martin','Luke','AAA'],"Job":['astronaut','biologist','director','footballer','waiter']})

df

User   Code   Job
Dan    001    astronaut
Mary   035    biologist
003    003    director
010   Martin  footballer
Luke   Luke   waiter
Peter  AAA    unkown
```

Given that I have a second dataframe - dictionary with the mapping of users and codes:

```
df_dict = pd.DataFrame({"name":['Dan','Paul','Julia','Mary','Martin','George','Daniel','Luke','Marina'],"code":['001','045','012','035','010','003','200','501']})

df_dict

name     code
Dan       001
Paul      045
Julia     012
Mary      035
Martin    010
George    003
Daniel    200
Marina    501
```

how can I do the mapping so that the first dataframe `df` looks like:

```
User   Code   Job
Dan    001    astronaut
Mary   035    biologist
George 003    director
Martin 010    footballer
Luke   200    waiter
Peter  AAA    unknown
```

Notice that if a value is not in the `df_dict` (like 'Peter' in this example) the record should remain as in the original `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Series` for mapping by first columns in [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace possible missing values by map by another columns, reasign columns in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and replace missing values by original values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
d1 = df_dict.set_index('name')['code']
d2 = df_dict.set_index('code')['name']

c = df['User'].map(d1).fillna(df['Code'].map(d1))
u = df['Code'].map(d2).fillna(df['User'].map(d2))

df = df.assign(Code=c, User=u).fillna(df)
print (df)
     User Code         Job
0     Dan  001   astronaut
1    Mary  035   biologist
2  George  003    director
3  Martin  010  footballer
4    Luke  200      waiter
5   Peter  AAA     unknown
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. I was trying with the `map` function but I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work correctly. Thanls @jezrael!